# Domain Driven Design - where should we put repositories?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am putting together a new system and I would like to have a rich domain for it. However, I am stuck on a little detail I want to know more about.

Suppose I would have a class Customer, where do you actually persist a customer entity or aggregate root?

should it be the customer class that has the knowledge of persistence?

```
var myCustomer = CustomerFactory.CreateCustomer(id);
myCustomer.Name = ...
myCustomer.LastName = ...

myCustomer.Save()
```

in this case I would need to pass my repository of Customers into the customer class (either via the factory or some injection). Notice that I could not find a good example of this in the DDD book by Eric Evens.

Another way is keeping the customer free of knowing about persistence

```
var myCustomer = CustomerFactory.CreateCustomer(id);
myCustomer.Name = ...
myCustomer.LastName = ...

CustomerRepository repository = new CustomerRepository();
repository.Save(myCustomer);
```

Also I suppose I can have a service class that does it all together like this:

```
AddCustomerService service = new AddCustomerService(CustomerRepository repository)
service.AddCustomer(myCustomer);
```

just a little note:
if I don't actually save in the customer class, I find that my customer class is nothing but properties, maybe with a little validation but nothing more. No real behavior is there. Behavior is moved either to service class or repositories used by the client...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a DDD project. There are 4 layers in this order (because I am not using WCF else there would be more):

```
1. UI
1.1 MVC4.csproj
... (Repository Interfaces)
... (Repository Implementations)

2. Service Layer
2.1 Service.cs 
...DTOs

3. Business Layer
3.1 DomainObjects.csproj

4. Data Access Layer
4.1 DAL.csproj (Entity framework 5)
... (Repository Interfaces)
... (Repository Implementations
```

Comment: Yes. I know.  But do your domain object hold a reference to your repositories?

Comment: No. there is no reference to the Repositories in my Domain Objects project.

Comment: Also, in case you haven't, I would seriously consider getting familiar with automapper because this architecture, great as it is, requires a mighty lot of mapping and automapper greatly reduces the chance of making mistakes in the mappings between the tiers.

Comment: Yes.  I know about auto mapper it's a must in these cases.   I wonder if you can show a simple example of persisting a domain object from a service.   Just to see the interaction. (Sudo code)

Comment: Are you looking for the code in the Service Layer or the code in the Data Layer?

Answer (score 2):

The latter is preferable. That is, write your save method in your CustomerRepository class. In DDD entities should be ignorant of persistence logic. It is quite common for your domain entities to not contain behaviour, and to only contain properties (although sometimes they should contain both).